# how to delay a specific line of code in php whilst the other line executes

Tags: php, cakephp, ussd

Im developing a ussd app which has a payment option in it.

The last message the user will receive on his phone is, "An amount of GHS 1 has been sent to your phone". This message always block the payment prompt to be received by the phone.
So how do I delay the payment prompt for some seconds so that is doesn't clash with the success message  ???

```
$transaction->updateTransactionDetails($transactionId, $reference, $request_id, SESSION_ID, MSISDN);                
echo   $RESPONSE_DATA = show("A Payment Prompt of GHS " . $totalAmount . " has been sent to your phone.", "end");
$push_payment =  $payment->momoPrompt($totalAmount,'MTN_MONEY',MSISDN,$reference, $request_id, $transactionId);
```

The payment prompt uses curl request

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Apologies, as I don't know much about Cake. Are these two conflicting messages both being rendered on the server side? Or are they being displayed via JavaScript? If it's simply a matter of making a server process avoid synchronous behavior, you might want to have a look at a tool like RabbitMQ, which can queue expensive tasks to be performed in the background while the user's workflow moves forward. But I'm about 75% sure I didn't understand your question fully, so I might be suggesting the solution to the wrong problem. Posting more code may get better answers.

Comment: In PHP you can use sleep() to slow the code down. But as the above commenter says, the scenario hasn't been fully explained I don't think and it's a bit unclear whether that would really be a suitable solution for what you need.

Comment: if I use the sleep(), it delays both the echo statement and the payment prompt. I want only the momoPrompt to be delayed while the echo statement still works.

Comment: it looks like your code runs inside a controller. You should move the output of the echo to the view of your application.